# How to implement custom filter algorithm for Ext.data.Store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to filter an Ext store using a custom algorithm. The JSON/AJAX proxy returns >100 records and I need to reduce the number to the top-5 based on a number of criteria.

How to go about this (not the algorithm but where to trigger it)?

My current approach is to use a custom reader like so

```
Ext.define('MyReader', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  alias : 'reader.myReader',

  getResponseData : function(response) {
    var data = this.callParent([response]);
    // algorithm
    return filteredData;
  }
});
Ext.define('SunApp.store.Stations', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: ['MyReader'],

  config: {
    model: 'SunApp.model.Station',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'data.json',
      reader: {
        type: 'myReader'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

but I'd much rather base the algorithm on the store model than on the raw JSON data. Hence, I'd like to filter while/after the data is loaded into the store. Note that the store is created implicitly by Ext when the list view is displayed:

```
Ext.define('SunApp.view.Stations', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'stations',

  config: {
    title: 'Stations',
    store: 'Stations',
    ...
```

Therefore, I can't just add a function to the store that I invoke manually before it's being passed to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case where the filter may need to traverse the store data (i.e. records) several times to reduce the full set to the desired set I *believe* (I'm still a Sencha rookie...) the following may be fine:

- write an on-load event listener
- do the magic filtering
- call `setData` on the store passing the filtered data

Hence, instead of filtering in the reader it'd be like this:

```
Ext.define('SunApp.store.Stations', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  config: {
    model: ...,
    sorters: [...],
    listeners: {
      load: function(store, records, success, eOpts) {
        var filteredRecords = filter(records);
        store.setData(filteredRecords);
      }
    },
    proxy: ...
  }
});
```